# Converting a external product to accept power from a voltage divider

Tags: power-supply, power

I'm currently working on converting [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B07MF99K26) voice recording module to accept power from a 9V power supply. I have successfully soldered the battery connections so the chip can be powered from two wires. When I connect the two wires directly to a 3.3~ishV power supply unit, the chip performs record and playback flawlessly. But when I attempt to wire it to a voltage divider, to wire down the voltage from 9v to the operating 3.3~ishV, the voltage going to the chip only appears to get around 2V (as opposed to the 3.45 that I would suspect). I tried increasing the input voltage from 9V to 12V and the chip still wants to hold at 2V.

[image: Circuit sketch]
Any ideas as to why this is happening? I suspect it has something to do with current, but I left my smarty pants at home today.

Comment: A voltage divider is completely, utterly, entirely unusable as a power supply. Stop trying to use a voltage divider as a power supply.

Comment: Yes, it has something to do with current. Think about the current the Chip requires and where this current is coming from. Maybe you can see why the voltage is lower than expected and why voltage dividers don't work well as power supply.

Comment: Petertk, Are you willing to consider getting two cheap NPN BJTs (silicons NPNs will do, so long as they still work okay) and a 1N750 zener diode? If so, you can wire up the BJTs into a Darlington arrangement and use the 1N750 as a 4.7 V voltage regulator for the Darlington base. If you want something written up on it, I'd be happy to do so. It's not perfect. But it will be worth a try, I suspect.

Comment: Yes this answers my question! thank you all. I have purchased a 3.3V voltage regulator and plan to use that.

Comment: @jonk I appreciate the offer, but I will likely just grab something off the shelf

Comment: @Petertk Understood.